# is it possible to shrink background image and keep the offsets

Tags: css

I have an image that contains multiple images with x and y offsets

Is it possible to use this offsets and then shrink the image to a different width and height ?

Here is a sample of the image i get and the desired output

Thanks in advance

```css
.container {
  width: 960px;
}

.full {
  background: url('http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/8.5.2/img/sprite/champion1.png') no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
}

.img-container {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px
}

.shrinked {
  background: url('http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/8.5.2/img/sprite/champion1.png') -48px -48px no-repeat;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  full image
  <div class="full"></div>

  40px centered
  <div class="img-container">
    <div class="shrinked"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You might be asking for css `clip` property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to achieve this using the `background-size` property and using `background-position` as percentage values.

For example, if the actual size of the thumbnail of the character is *50x50* and you want to get it down to *40x40*, you can set the `background-size` property as 80% of the dimensions of the image.

Considering the your image size is *480x144*, your `background-size` would be *384x115.2*.

Also, while using percentage values for `background-position` make sure you 
are clear with the way it works. [This](https://css-tricks.com/i-like-how-percentage-background-position-works/) should help you with that.

Here is an updated version of your [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/maitreyjukar/cc8p77Lt/1/).